# C# No me deja consumir webservice de manera local

Tags: c#, asp.net, webservice, cliente

Estoy trabajando con visual studio creando un webservice de ASP.net, de hecho estoy siguiendo un tutorial al pie de la letra, el método que viene por defecto al crear un ASMX es

```
[WebMethod]
    public string HolaMundo()
    {
        return "Hola a todos";
    }
```

Y siguiendo el mismo tutorial, ya publiqué el webservice de prueba en IIS, mi link queda como "http://localhost:8081/BackEndDescargaMasiva.asmx", (así le puse porque estaba pensando usarlo en otro proyecto, ignorar el nombre) ya estando publicado correctamente de manera local, al crear un cliente que lo consuma, se crea un proyecto de consola, se agrega la referencia y me detecta el método correctamente, al intentar consumirlo utilizo este código:

```
backend1.BackEndDescargaMasivaSoapClient client = new backend1.BackEndDescargaMasivaSoapClient();
        var result = client.HolaMundo();
        Console.WriteLine(result);
        Console.ReadLine();
```

Pero cuando ejecuto me arroja lo siguiente:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

esto es lo que dice:

```
System.ServiceModel.FaultException  
  HResult=0x80131501  
  Mensaje = System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapException: El servidor no puede procesar la solicitud. ---> System.InvalidOperationException: No se puede serializar System.Security.Cryptography.KeySizes porque no tiene un constructor sin parámetros.  
   en System.Xml.Serialization.TypeDesc.CheckSupported()  
   en System.Xml.Serialization.TypeScope.GetTypeDesc(Type type, MemberInfo source, Boolean directReference, Boolean throwOnError)  
   en System.Xml.Serialization.ReflectionAwareILGen.WriteReflectionInit(TypeScope scope)  
   en System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializationWriterILGen.GenerateBegin()  
   en   System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly.GenerateRefEmitAssembly(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, Evidence evidence)  
   en System.Xml.Serialization.TempAssembly..ctor(XmlMapping[] xmlMappings, Type[] types, String defaultNamespace, String location, Evidence evidence)  
   en System.Xml.Serialization.XmlSerializer.FromMappings(XmlMapping[] mappings, Type type)  
   en System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerType..ctor(Type type, WebServiceProtocols protocolsSupported)  
   en System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapServerProtocol.Initialize()  
   en System.Web.Services.Protocols.ServerProtocolFactory.Create(Type type, HttpContext context, HttpRequest request, HttpResponse response, Boolean& abortProcessing)  
   --- Fin del seguimiento de la pila de la excepción interna ---  
  Origen = mscorlib  
  Seguimiento de la pila:  
   en System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.HandleReturnMessage(IMessage reqMsg, IMessage retMsg)
   en System.Runtime.Remoting.Proxies.RealProxy.PrivateInvoke(MessageData& msgData, Int32 type)
   en Consumo_de_servicio.backend1.BackEndDescargaMasivaSoap.HolaMundo()
   en Consumo_de_servicio.backend1.BackEndDescargaMasivaSoapClient.HolaMundo() en C:\Users\DCL-Admin\source\repos\Consumo de servicio\Consumo de servicio\Connected Services\backend1\Reference.cs: línea 305
   en Consumo_de_servicio.Program.Main(String[] args) en C:\Users\DCL-Admin\source\repos\Consumo de servicio\Consumo de servicio\Program.cs: línea 14
```